# php manipulations with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I did connection to the DB with PHP code, everything ok. BUT i can't do any manipulations in DB with PHP code, f.e. add/edit tables.
here is piece of code:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "mypass", "mybase");
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    // editing existing table
    $success = $mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `myBase`.`users` (`login`, `password`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('aaa', '".md5("123")."', '".time()."')");
    echo $success; // this echo does not work

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

No new user after this edit.

Comment: What does your PHP error log say?

Comment: No php error log. When i change f.e. password to wrongPass - php log says that it is wrong, but when everything ok in mysqli connection - no errors.

Comment: Do a `print_r($success)` to see more instead of `echo`. i also saw in the docs comments that a `$result->fetch_object()` is performed on the query result. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I used print_r($success), but problem was the same (nothing shown). I entered the link that you gave, and at the end of page was code, and it also does not do anything.
I am using apache2, not denwer (may be there is any difference?)

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging with

```
echo $mysqli->error;
```

Generally, errors that prevent you from inserting into your table are syntax or user database permissions.

Comment: oh GOD man, thank you very much. The problem was here: ("INSERT INTO `myBase`.`users` ...")
myBase not needed, error says: Table 'myBase.users' doesn't exist

Comment: Help me once more pls.
I made form with email. Do you know where sent email stores ? (Ubuntu apache2)

Comment: I don't know, but this may help you.

http://martinvalasek.com/blog/how-to-catch-emails-sent-with-php-on-your-local-server